# Clearing files from clipboardData - window:paste

Tags: javascript, angular, clipboard

Can we somehow clear `$event.dataTransfer.files` in angular or in js.
here is my code:

```
 @HostListener('window:paste', ['$event'])
  onPaste($event) {
    this.uploadImagesByDndOrPaste({
      dataTransfer: $event.clipboardData,
    });
```

```
uploadImagesByDndOrPaste method:

if ($event.dataTransfer.files.length) {
      const files = $event.dataTransfer.files;
      [...files].forEach((file, i) => {
```

Is there any way I can clear `$event.dataTransfer.files` in my code?
Note: The requirement is to copy any file from the internet and paste it in our page.

Comment: Do you want to clear it from the clipboard, or from the event, i.e do you want the files to be gone and the user unable to paste it somewhere else, or do you just want future event handlers in your page to not see them.

Comment: I am trying to delete the file object from clipboardData files array

Comment: Since it doesn't have any setter it throws exception

Comment: But why? What is the end goal. If it's only for your script to not see these, why not make your script ignore it? If you really need to, you can build a new DataTransfer and pass this instead of the real one, but that sounds like an x-y problem.